# python/tkinter screen stops displaying canvas updates

Tags: python, tkinter, garbage-collection, tkinter-canvas, mouse-cursor

I have a program that updates (complete image recreation ie rotate image) then changes the tkinter.canvas.image and then calls canvas.updatestats() to force changes to screen.  time.sleep(0.0001) is called and process repeats itself.

It works perfectly until the mouse pointer changes to a tiny blue circle with a lighter bar circling the blue circle.  If I move the mouse pointer, the circle moves correspondingly. Maybe 30 seconds later the circle returns to the mouse pointer and the screen instantly changes to what it should look like after 30 seconds of operation (at that point the screen is 100% correct for 30 seconds of operation).  However during the appearance of the blue circle the screen is no longer updated.  I suspect that it is that a possible garbage collection has started and causes tkinter to work correctly but screen update is suspended.  It takes awhile for this to start, but then happens often.

I tried importing gc.  And then executed gc.disable() but that did not help.

Does anyone know for sure why this is happening?

Is there any way to stop this happening?

Can my program determine that this stoppage of screen updating is taking place, so I can suspend my screen updates until it is done?

Comment: It's hard to say without knowing what your code looks like. Can you post a [mcve] that reproduces this problem? BTW, it's generally not a good idea to call `time.sleep` in a GUI program because that puts _everything_ to sleep, so the GUI can't update itself or respond to user input. I guess a 0.1 of a millisecond delay won't hurt anything, OTOH, `.sleep` may sleep longer than requested if the system is busy.

Comment: No, I can't.  It's probably about a thousand lines of code just to set up all the data structures needed to get to this point.

Answer (score 0):

This is the loop that is being executed when the problem occurs.  Remember the code works and produces the correct output, except for when the blue circle replaces the mouse pointer at that point the code continues to execute correctly, its just that the screen is not updated during the 30 second delay and when the blue circle finally disappears the net result of the 30 seconds of execution is displayed.  No where in my code do I change the mouse pointer.

This is a Windows 10 machine, and python 3.6.

```
    while (fx != tx or fy != ty):
        if fx == tx:
            dx = 0
        elif fx > tx:
            dx = -2 if fx != tx+1 else -1
        else:
            dx =  2 if fx != tx-1 else  1
        if fy == ty:
            dy = 0
        elif fy > ty:
            dy = -2 if fy != ty+1 else -1
        else:
            dy =  2 if fy != ty-1 else  1
        steps += 1
        if steps > 0:
            if sAngle != eAngle:
                if eAngle < sAngle: sAngle -= 2
                else:               sAngle += 2
                im = Image.new("RGBA",(int(tileHeight+tileWidth/2),int(tileHeight+tileWidth/2)))
                if til.direction == North or til.direction == South:
                    im.paste(til.dom.raw[til.direction],(int((tileHeight+tileWidth/2-tileWidth)/2),int(tileWidth/4)))
                else:
                    im.paste(til.dom.raw[til.direction],(int(tileWidth/4),int((tileHeight+tileWidth/2-tileWidth)/2)))
                im = im.rotate(sAngle)
                imm = ImageTk.PhotoImage(im)        
                CANVAS.delete(til.canvasID)
                tags.remove(til.canvasID)
                til.canvasID = CANVAS.create_image(fx,fy,anchor=tk.CENTER,image=imm)
                tags.append(til.canvasID)

        CANVAS.move(til.canvasID,dx,dy)
        fx += dx
        fy += dy
        CANVAS.update_idletasks()
        time.sleep(0.0000001)
```

Comment: This info isn't an answer, it's part of your question, so it belongs in your question, not here in the Answers section.

Comment: But anyway, I can't see anything here that would cause your problem. However, you can make that code more efficient. Don't delete the canvas image item & create a new one. Just update the `photo` attribute of the existing image item.